# How to read all the list of values present in the drop down using selenium webdriver java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please help me in reading all the list of values present under my Goal Type drop down present in the Salesforce application:

HTML:

```html
<select id="00N20000002gQI3" name="00N20000002gQI3" tabindex="3">
    <option value="">--None--</option>
    <option value="Asset Finance">Asset Finance</option>
    <option value="Barcap">Barcap</option>
    <option value="Barclaycard">Barclaycard</option>
    <option value="Barclays Wealth">Barclays Wealth</option>
    <option value="BGI">BGI</option>
    <option value="Cash Management">Cash Management</option>
    <option value="DCM">DCM</option>
    <option value="Debt">Debt</option>
    <option value="Deposit">Deposit</option>
    <option value="ECM">ECM</option>
    <option value="ESHLA">ESHLA</option>
    <option value="Financial Need Assessment">Financial Need Assessment</option>
    <option value="FX">FX</option>
    <option value="Generic">Generic</option>
    <option value="Individual Relationship">Individual Relationship</option>
    <option value="M&amp;A">M&amp;A</option>
    <option value="Managing Impairment">Managing Impairment</option>
    <option value="Managing RWAs">Managing RWAs</option>
    <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
    <option value="Overall Relationship">Overall Relationship</option>
    <option value="RSG">RSG</option>
    <option value="Sales Finance">Sales Finance</option>
    <option value="Trade">Trade</option>
</select>
```

Please let me know how can I read all the values present in the drop down... If you can share the code that will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use this, it should return an array of all the *option* elements:

```
element_array = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='00N20000002gQI3']/option"))
```

So you can just extract the text of each element from this array. There's no need to click on the elements.

```
element_array[1].text
element_array[2].text
```

and etc.

Comment: Thanks Nora.. it worked. I had to reiterate to show the value. Because by default it shows the first value..

Comment: you can use"//select[@id='00N20000002gQI3']/option[1]" "//select[@id='00N20000002gQI3']/option[2]", etc

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method I have used before to select an option by value:

```
public static void selectInDropdownByValue(WebElement we, String val) {
    Select dropDown = new Select(we);           
    List<WebElement> theseOptions = dropDown.getOptions();
    for(WebElement option:theseOptions){
        if(option.getAttribute("value").equals(val)){
            option.click();  
        }
    }   
}
```

Sometimes, with some menus, this won't be enough.  In that case you need to use a WebDriver "Action" to physically move the mouse and click the mouse button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getOptions function of Select class.
Loop through the list of webelements received and call getText to get the visible options..something like

```
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement("yourlocator");
List of WebElements lst = sel.getOptions();
//iterate list with getText
```